# how does subversive place author name beside file in eclipse explorer

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin

I would like to know how subversive/subclipse place author name(the person who committed the file recently) beside file in eclipse explorer. I have been reading in plugin development guide of eclipse for quite sometime now and I cant seem to find which extension is capable of making this. I have also read that the term is Showing Annotation?

I would really appreciate if someone could give me an idea how subversive/subclipse does it. I will continue reading.

Thank you.

Comment: Did you look at the source code?

Comment: You are actually looking at two different terms: "Label decorations" are the additional things one can have at any label (e.g. in the project explorer), while "Show annotations" is the command used to show the last author of each line of the currently opened file in the left hand ruler column of the active editor.

Answer (score 0):

This is a label decorator declared using the `org.eclipse.ui.decorators` extension point and using a class which implements `org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ILightweightLabelDecorator`